# Decorating date formats

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I'm looking for a way to parse a string which would replace some patterns with components of a date that I provide.

Do you know of a standard way to do this?

One usage would be:

```
parseForDate("fileName%YYYY%MM.csv", new Date()); // returns: filename201301.csv
```

Best regards

Comment: I would suggest you to use [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) in combination with the already mentioned [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html):

```
String filename = String.format("fileName%1$tY%1$tm.csv", new Date());
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just felt there was a standard way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
String filename = "fileName%" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy%MM").format(new Date())+".csv"; // returns: filename201301.csv
```